# Upload file on easyupload.io with curl linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

I tried to upload file on file.io which has api using curl -F "file=@filename.txt" "https://file.io/"

how to achieve this using easyupload.io and validate that file is uploaded properly and also display the url for the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easyupload.io uses Google Captcha in the background to prevent automatic uploading.

So I guess if there is no specific API for this site, it's not meant to be used with a script / program.

You can reverse engineer the upload process by opening the network tab in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: ok so is there any way to upload the file to easyupload.io using script or curl

Comment: I don't think so, Google reCAPTCHA is used to verify the request originated from a human being and not a script / program. As far as I can tell, there is no information about an API for automated upload on that site.